# org.hibernate.MappingException: Composite-id class must implement Serializable: gr.gourvas.platform.model.TransferObjects.Incident

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have two projects that are almost the same. Simple customization differences exist between them. Till yesterday they both build just fine. After making some changes, one of them can't be built with errors i can't really figure out. The backend is build in java-ee as a restful web api, and i use apache shiro for authentication/authorization.

The one that fails to build, throws the following errors:
**In Java Output Console:**

```
/Users/mixtou/apache-tomcat-9.0.10/bin/catalina.sh run
[2018-11-13 04:32:29,560] Artifact Gourvas-Platform-Web-App-Exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
13-Nov-2018 16:32:30.605 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.10
13-Nov-2018 16:32:30.608 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jun 20 2018 17:32:21 UTC
13-Nov-2018 16:32:30.608 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         9.0.10.0
13-Nov-2018 16:32:30.609 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Mac OS X
13-Nov-2018 16:32:30.609 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.13.6
13-Nov-2018 16:32:30.609 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          x86_64
13-Nov-2018 16:32:30.609 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
13-Nov-2018 16:32:30.610 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_65-b17
13-Nov-2018 16:32:30.610 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
13-Nov-2018 16:32:30.610 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /Users/mixtou/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2018.2/tomcat/Unnamed_Gourvas-HistopathPlatform
13-Nov-2018 16:32:30.610 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /Users/mixtou/apache-tomcat-9.0.10
13-Nov-2018 16:32:30.611 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/Users/mixtou/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2018.2/tomcat/Unnamed_Gourvas-HistopathPlatform/conf/logging.properties
13-Nov-2018 16:32:30.612 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
13-Nov-2018 16:32:30.612 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
13-Nov-2018 16:32:30.614 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
13-Nov-2018 16:32:30.614 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
13-Nov-2018 16:32:30.614 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
13-Nov-2018 16:32:30.614 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
13-Nov-2018 16:32:30.614 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
13-Nov-2018 16:32:30.615 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
13-Nov-2018 16:32:30.615 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
13-Nov-2018 16:32:30.615 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
13-Nov-2018 16:32:30.615 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/Users/mixtou/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2018.2/tomcat/Unnamed_Gourvas-HistopathPlatform
13-Nov-2018 16:32:30.615 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/Users/mixtou/apache-tomcat-9.0.10
13-Nov-2018 16:32:30.615 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/Users/mixtou/apache-tomcat-9.0.10/temp
13-Nov-2018 16:32:30.616 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/mixtou/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
13-Nov-2018 16:32:30.759 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
13-Nov-2018 16:32:30.787 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
13-Nov-2018 16:32:30.794 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
13-Nov-2018 16:32:30.796 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
13-Nov-2018 16:32:30.804 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 539 ms
13-Nov-2018 16:32:30.852 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
13-Nov-2018 16:32:30.853 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.10
13-Nov-2018 16:32:30.871 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
13-Nov-2018 16:32:30.892 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
13-Nov-2018 16:32:30.897 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 93 ms
Connected to server
[2018-11-13 04:32:31,154] Artifact Gourvas-Platform-Web-App-Exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
13-Nov-2018 16:32:35.611 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
MLog initialization issue: slf4j found no binding or threatened to use its (dangerously silent) NOPLogger. We consider the slf4j library not found.
13-Nov-2018 16:32:37.876 INFO [MLog-Init-Reporter] com.mchange.v2.log.MLog. MLog clients using java 1.4+ standard logging.
13-Nov-2018 16:32:37.954 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry. Initializing c3p0-0.9.5.2 [built 08-December-2015 22:06:04 -0800; debug? true; trace: 10]
13-Nov-2018 16:32:38.027 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource. Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource@64a7a15e [ connectionPoolDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource@b258231 [ acquireIncrement -> 1, acquireRetryAttempts -> 1, acquireRetryDelay -> 250, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, contextClassLoaderSource -> caller, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, forceSynchronousCheckins -> false, identityToken -> 1hge13s9z3qqd5o127reqb|6ffdc108, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 60, initialPoolSize -> 5, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 0, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 20, maxStatements -> 50, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 5, nestedDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource@b4f13878 [ description -> null, driverClass -> null, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceUseNamedDriverClass -> false, identityToken -> 1hge13s9z3qqd5o127reqb|772538d9, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gourvas_platform?useSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=Europe/Athens, properties -> {useUnicode=true, user=******, password=******, CharSet=utf8, characterEncoding=utf8} ], preferredTestQuery -> null, privilegeSpawnedThreads -> false, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false; userOverrides: {} ], dataSourceName -> null, extensions -> {}, factoryClassLocation -> null, identityToken -> 1hge13s9z3qqd5o127reqb|77a5c8e3, numHelperThreads -> 3 ]
13-Nov-2018 16:32:38.989 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
13-Nov-2018 16:32:38.993 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
13-Nov-2018 16:32:38.999 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [ROOT] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
[2018-11-13 04:32:39,011] Artifact Gourvas-Platform-Web-App-Exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
13-Nov-2018 16:32:40.815 INFO [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1329)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1006)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.checkContextClassLoaders(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:96)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:69)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

13-Nov-2018 16:32:40.877 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/Users/mixtou/apache-tomcat-9.0.10/webapps/manager]
13-Nov-2018 16:32:40.913 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/Users/mixtou/apache-tomcat-9.0.10/webapps/manager] has finished in [36] ms
13-Nov-2018 16:33:38.053 INFO [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hge13s9z3qqd5o127reqb|77a5c8e3]-AdminTaskTimer] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1329)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1176)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1138)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkIdleResources(BasicResourcePool.java:1635)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$2000(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$CheckIdleResourcesTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:2176)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

Exception in thread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hge13s9z3qqd5o127reqb|77a5c8e3]-AdminTaskTimer" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mchange/v2/resourcepool/BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkIdleResources(BasicResourcePool.java:1635)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$2000(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$CheckIdleResourcesTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:2176)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1319)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1176)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1138)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1329)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1317)
    ... 7 more
[2018-11-13 05:14:58,023] Artifact Gourvas-Platform-Web-App-Exploded: Artifact is not deployed. Press 'Deploy' to start deployment
```

**Inside Tomcat Log:**

```
13-Nov-2018 16:32:35.624 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Shiro environment
13-Nov-2018 16:32:38.989 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener]
 org.apache.shiro.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to instantiate class [gr.gourvas.platform.lib.MyRealm] for object named 'jdbcRealm'.  Please ensure you've specified the fully qualified class name correctly.
    at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.createNewInstance(ReflectionBuilder.java:309)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder$InstantiationStatement.doExecute(ReflectionBuilder.java:927)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder$Statement.execute(ReflectionBuilder.java:887)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder$BeanConfigurationProcessor.execute(ReflectionBuilder.java:765)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.buildObjects(ReflectionBuilder.java:260)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.buildInstances(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:167)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createSecurityManager(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:130)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createSecurityManager(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createInstance(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:94)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createInstance(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:46)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniFactorySupport.createInstance(IniFactorySupport.java:123)
    at org.apache.shiro.util.AbstractFactory.getInstance(AbstractFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.env.IniWebEnvironment.createWebSecurityManager(IniWebEnvironment.java:203)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.env.IniWebEnvironment.configure(IniWebEnvironment.java:99)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.env.IniWebEnvironment.init(IniWebEnvironment.java:92)
    at org.apache.shiro.util.LifecycleUtils.init(LifecycleUtils.java:45)
    at org.apache.shiro.util.LifecycleUtils.init(LifecycleUtils.java:40)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoader.createEnvironment(EnvironmentLoader.java:221)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoader.initEnvironment(EnvironmentLoader.java:133)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener.contextInitialized(EnvironmentLoaderListener.java:58)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4643)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5109)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:718)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:703)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1737)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:457)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:406)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1471)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1312)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1404)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:832)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$256(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.shiro.util.InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate class [gr.gourvas.platform.lib.MyRealm]
    at org.apache.shiro.util.ClassUtils.newInstance(ClassUtils.java:183)
    at org.apache.shiro.util.ClassUtils.newInstance(ClassUtils.java:168)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.createNewInstance(ReflectionBuilder.java:302)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: PersistenceUnit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1016)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:942)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:56)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at gr.gourvas.platform.model.DAO.SingletonFactory.<init>(SingletonFactory.java:13)
    at gr.gourvas.platform.model.DAO.AbstractDAO.<init>(AbstractDAO.java:14)
    at gr.gourvas.platform.model.DAO.UserDAO.<init>(UserDAO.java:8)
    at gr.gourvas.platform.lib.MyRealm.<init>(MyRealm.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.apache.shiro.util.ClassUtils.newInstance(ClassUtils.java:181)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Composite-id class must implement Serializable: gr.gourvas.platform.model.TransferObjects.Incident
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.checkCompositeIdentifier(RootClass.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:276)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:347)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:466)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939)
    ... 79 more

13-Nov-2018 16:32:38.997 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Cleaning up Shiro Environment
```

I googled the errors but i can't figure out why suddenly this started happening, while the other project builds just fine.

**My shiro.ini (Working Implementation)**

```
[main]
jwtg = gr.histopath.platform.lib.JWTGuard
jwtv =  gr.histopath.platform.lib.JWTVerifyingFilter

ds = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource
ds.serverName = 127.0.0.1
ds.port = 3306
ds.user = histopathUser
ds.password = ********
ds.databaseName = histopath.gr

jdbcRealm = gr.histopath.platform.lib.MyRealm
jdbcRealm.dataSource = $ds

credentialsMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.Sha512CredentialsMatcher
credentialsMatcher.hashIterations = 50000
credentialsMatcher.hashSalted = true
credentialsMatcher.storedCredentialsHexEncoded = false
jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $credentialsMatcher

jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = false

shiro.loginUrl = /authentication/login

cacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager
securityManager.cacheManager = $cacheManager

sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager
#securityManager.sessionManager.sessionIdCookieEnabled = false

# ssl.enabled = false

securityManager.realms = $jdbcRealm

[users]

[roles]

[urls]

/authentication/login = authc
# /authentication/logout = logout

/search/* = noSessionCreation, jwtv
/statistics/* = noSessionCreation, jwtv
/clinics/* = noSessionCreation, jwtv
/patients/* = noSessionCreation, jwtv
/incidents/* = noSessionCreation, jwtv
/doctors/* = noSessionCreation, jwtv

/users/new = noSessionCreation, anon
/users/details/* = noSessionCreation, anon
/users/* = noSessionCreation, jwtv

/* = anon
```

**Shiro.ini (NOT WORKING)**

```
[main]
jwtg = gr.gourvas.platform.lib.JWTGuard
jwtv =  gr.gourvas.platform.lib.JWTVerifyingFilter

ds = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource
ds.serverName = 127.0.0.1
ds.port = 3306
ds.user = gourvasUser
ds.password = ********
ds.databaseName = gourvas_platform


jdbcRealm = gr.gourvas.platform.lib.MyRealm
jdbcRealm.dataSource = $ds

credentialsMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.Sha512CredentialsMatcher
credentialsMatcher.hashIterations = 50000
credentialsMatcher.hashSalted = true
credentialsMatcher.storedCredentialsHexEncoded = false
jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $credentialsMatcher


jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = false

shiro.loginUrl = /authentication/login

cacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager
securityManager.cacheManager = $cacheManager

sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager
#securityManager.sessionManager.sessionIdCookieEnabled = false

# ssl.enabled = false

securityManager.realms = $jdbcRealm

[users]

[roles]

[urls]

/authentication/login = authc
# /authentication/logout = logout

/search/* = noSessionCreation, jwtv
/statistics/* = noSessionCreation, jwtv
/clinics/* = noSessionCreation, jwtv
/patients/* = noSessionCreation, jwtv
/incidents/* = noSessionCreation, jwtv
/doctors/* = noSessionCreation, jwtv

/users/new = noSessionCreation, anon
/users/details/* = noSessionCreation, anon

/users/* = noSessionCreation, jwtv

/* = anon
```

Any Ideas where the Problem is?? Why the one works and the other doesn't??
I am banging my head a few hours without any success... Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with Hibernate. I had made some changes to Database Tables and Related Transfer Objects. However for the Incident Transfer Object i had to *implement Serializable*. Then everything worked fine.

My question is why isn't build process failing and Hibernate isn't complaining about the other Transfer Objects that had been changed (to be Serializable) and only for the Incident Table??

Answer (score 0):

This happened to this Transfer Object (Incident) because accidentally a 
second column was annotated with @Id instead of @Basic. So this created a 
*composite-id* which lead to the *Serialization Error*. By replacing @Id 
annotation in the second column/field with @Basic project builds normally 
without the implementation of Serializable.